# Javascript using constructor inside in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I have code like this, then I was confused on how to loop the array family
to print each member under person.

```
function Person(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}


var family = [];
family[0] = new Person("alice",40);
family[1] = new Person("bob",42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle",8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy",6);
```

Comment: So you're asking how objects _work_ ? Heres a hint: look up the `for` loop, then look up `javascript objects`. If you cant figure it out then take a tutorial or two. This isn't even a question... How about `for(person in family){ alert(family[person].name); }`... See how simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cta0gay2/)

is that what you need ?

```
for (var key in family) {
   var obj = family[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
   }
}
```

Here is the way to access the properties directly and not with a loop [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cta0gay2/1/) (Method 2, uncomment)

Comment: I try also doing a different way by my self like this code basing on your code.

for(var name = 0; name < family.length;name++)
{
    console.log('Name: ' + family[name]["name"] + ' Age: ' + family[name]["age"]);
    }